# scroll by number of elements on jquery-just-another-carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel, carousel

It is possible to scroll by fixed number of child items that will be specified on configuration for jquery-just-another-carousel.

Like when we click Next or Previous link then the carousel will be scrolled by 2 child items.

http://intrepidstudios.com/projects/jquery-just-another-carousel/documentation.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory look at the source code, it appears that the plugin is only meant to scroll one child at a time. It would take modification of the source code to do what you require. So to save us both a lot of work, have you looked at alternatives?

- [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) (see [this example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html))
- [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)

---

Update: Ok making the modification to scroll just 1/2 the view port window was much easier! I posted a [demo for you here](http://jsbin.com/ufuru3/). But instead of making the modification permanent, I decided to make it an option - these are the settings I used with the new option "moveHalfViewPortWidth" set to true:

```
 var jac2 = {
  enableMouse : false,
  childSizeFixed : false,
  moveHalfViewPortWidth : true 
 };

 // Setup galleries
 $(".jac2").jac(jac2);
```

download the modified plugin from [here](http://www.myotherdrive.com/dyn/file/722.333809.11042010.11508.6a64fi/jquery.jac.js).

Comment: I also tried with jCarousel but the problem is that it require fixed width for child items. And it is not working somehow on Chrome. Width for each child items on my Carousel will be different. I'm not sure about "Anything Slider", either it works or not. But so far jquery-just-another-carousel is the one which is working as per my requirement except scrolling by fixed number of child items.

Comment: can you help me to modify the javascript code so that I am able to slide only the half of viewport width? JS File: http://intrepidstudios.com/lib/js/100/jquery.plugins/jquery.jac.js

Comment: @Prakash: Ok, I've updated my answer. I hope that is what you wanted!